# Fade out siblings on hover using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to fade out sibling elements of a list when an li is hovered on and fade back when hovered off. I know this can be done using CSS but it won't work to the exact same degree as I'd like. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton");
body {
  background: #F4D35E;
}

ul {
  List-style: none;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 100px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #DA4167;
  font-family: 'Anton', serif;
  font-size: 300px;
  margin: 0px 50px;
}

ul li:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).siblings().addClass('fade-out');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('fade-out');
  }
);
```

Set the fade out style on `.fade-out` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).siblings().addClass('fade-out');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('fade-out');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton");
body {
  background: #F4D35E;
}

ul {
  List-style: none;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 100px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Anton', serif;
  font-size: 300px;
  margin: 0px 50px;
  color: rgba(218, 65, 103, 1);
  transition: color .2s;
}

ul li:hover {
  color: white;
}

.fade-out {
  color: rgba(218, 65, 103, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My only question is. The transition doesn't look too good when the mouse cursors leave the elements. I'd like it to transition on the way out too...

Comment: @samsos Just make sure you have `transition` set like what did in the example above.